# McLaurin on $\sqrt{(\frac{n+n^2}{n^2+2n^3}})$

Tags: analysis

I have expanded $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt{(\frac{n+n^2}{n^2+2n^3}})$ to $(\frac{1}{4n}+o(..))$ I thought I had done everything correctly, but when i check my result on wolfram alpha i get this result $\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}}{\sqrt{2}}+...$  I can't figure out how get this! I developed the fraction and I call the result $t$ and after I develop  $\sqrt{t}$, I've wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the radical, for large values of "n", you basically have n^2 / (2 n^3) = (1 / (2 n). So build the expansion of the radical multiplied Sqrt[n] and then insert "n" inside the radical which becomes (n^2 + n^3) /(n^2 + 2 n^3) which is almost (1/2). When you have your expansion, divide it by Sqrt[n].

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\left(\frac{n+n^2}{n^2+2n^3}\right)^{1/2}=\frac{1}{n\sqrt 2}\left(\frac{1+\frac 1 n}{1+\frac 1{2n}}\right)^{1/2}=\frac{1}{n\sqrt 2}\left(\left(1+\frac 1 n\right)\left(1-\frac 1{2n}+O\left(\frac 1{n^2}\right)\right)\right)^{1/2}\\=\frac{1}{n\sqrt 2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}+O\left(\frac 1{n^2}\right)\right)^{1/2}=\frac{1}{n\sqrt 2}\left(1+\frac{1}{4n}+O\left(\frac 1{n^2}\right)\right)\\=\frac{1}{n\sqrt 2}+\frac{1}{4n^2\sqrt 2}+O\left(\frac 1{n^3}\right)$$

Comment: It's wrong.. It must be $\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}}{\sqrt{2}}+o(...)$

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you explicitly expand the fraction:
for $n$ large, it holds
$$ \frac{n+n^2}{n^2+2n^3} = \frac{1/n + 1}{1+2n}
 =\frac{1}{2n} \frac{1 + 1/n}{1 + 1/2n}  =\frac{1}{2n} \left(1 + \frac{1/2n}{1 + 1/2n} \right) $$
Then you can take the square root to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the limit of the expression you can go directly with the fact that $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is continuous and leave the square root sign.

As the function argument $\frac{n+n^2}{n^2+2n^3} = \frac{\frac{1}{n}+1}{1+2n} = \left( \frac{1}{n}+1 \right) \left(\frac{1}{1+2n} \right) \rightarrow 0$ so does $\sqrt{\frac{n+n^2}{n^2+2n^3}} \to 0$